# Node isn't waiting for an callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I have the following code:

```
module.exports.getFinancialDashboard = function(req,res){
    console.log("getFinancialDashboard");    
    if(req && req.query.shopSlug){
        shopService.getShopFromSlug(req.query.shopSlug, function(err, shop){
            var status, response;

            var outStandingOrders = 0;
            var nextPaymentDate = new Date();
            var nextPayment =0;
            var revenue = 0;
            var expectedRevenue = 0;
            var orderCount =0;

            if(err) {
                status = 500;
                response = {message: 'Internal server error. ' + err};
                return res.status(status).json(response);
            }

            Payment.find({shopId: shop._id}).exec(function(err, payments){
                if(err) {
                    status = 500;
                    response = {message: 'Internal server error. ' + err};
                    return res.status(status).json(response);
                }

                async.forEachOf(payments, function(payment, i, paymentDone){
                    parsePayment(payment, function(err, paymentRevenue, paymentExpectedRevenue){
                        orderCount= i+1;
                        if(err){
                            console.log("ERROR:", err);
                        }
                        if(paymentRevenue){
                            revenue = revenue + paymentRevenue;
                        }
                        if(paymentExpectedRevenue){
                            expectedRevenue = expectedRevenue + paymentExpectedRevenue;
                            outStandingOrders++;
                        }
                    })

                    paymentDone();
                }, function(){

                    console.log("revenue", revenue);
                    console.log("expected", expectedRevenue);
                    console.log("ordercount", orderCount, "paymentslength", payments.length);
                    if(orderCount == payments.length){
                        var dashboard = {
                            outStandingOrders: outStandingOrders,
                            nextPaymentDate: nextPaymentDate,
                            payment: nextPayment,
                            revenue: revenue,
                            expectedRevenue: expectedRevenue
                        }
                        console.log("DAS", dashboard);

                        status = 200;
                        response = {message: 'OK', dashboard};
                        return res.status(status).json(response);
                   }
                })
            })
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'No details provided'});
    }
}


function parsePayment(payment, callback){

    var revenue = 0, expectedRevenue =0;

    if(payment.amount > 0){
        if(payment.completed && payment.exported){
            console.log("completed payment");
           return callback(null, payment.amount);
        }else{
            Order.findOne({_id: payment.orderId}).exec(function(err, order){
                if (err){
                    return callback(err);
                }
                if(orderService.getOrderStatus(order) == "Send"){
                    console.log("sended order");
                    return callback(null, null, payment.amount);
                }else{
                    return callback();
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I want to have all the parsed data before sending it back, but nodeJS isn't waiting despite the callback. I get the following in my console:

```
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
completed payment
revenue 3022.6799174
expected 0
ordercount 23 paymentslength 24
sended order
```

As you can see, I get 'revenue', 'expected' and 'ordercount' before the last 'sended order'.
And because that, ordercount isn't equal to payments.length so, I never receive the result.

I have tried it with different functions from the async libary like forEach and ForEachSeries, a simple for loop without callbacks at all, but this won't working.

I think it is a simple mistake I made, but I can't find it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code didn't wait last one because parsePayment is async function and you call paymentDone before it done.

you need to put paymentDone in parsePayment function callback

```
module.exports.getFinancialDashboard = function(req,res){
    console.log("getFinancialDashboard");    
    if(req && req.query.shopSlug){
        shopService.getShopFromSlug(req.query.shopSlug, function(err, shop){
            var status, response;

            var outStandingOrders = 0;
            var nextPaymentDate = new Date();
            var nextPayment =0;
            var revenue = 0;
            var expectedRevenue = 0;
            var orderCount =0;

            if(err) {
                status = 500;
                response = {message: 'Internal server error. ' + err};
                return res.status(status).json(response);
            }

            Payment.find({shopId: shop._id}).exec(function(err, payments){
                if(err) {
                    status = 500;
                    response = {message: 'Internal server error. ' + err};
                    return res.status(status).json(response);
                }

                async.forEachOf(payments, function(payment, i, paymentDone){
                    parsePayment(payment, function(err, paymentRevenue, paymentExpectedRevenue){
                        orderCount= i+1;
                        if(err){
                            console.log("ERROR:", err);
                        }
                        if(paymentRevenue){
                            revenue = revenue + paymentRevenue;
                        }
                        if(paymentExpectedRevenue){
                            expectedRevenue = expectedRevenue + paymentExpectedRevenue;
                            outStandingOrders++;
                        }
                        paymentDone(); // <-- move to callback
                    })

                }, function(){

                    console.log("revenue", revenue);
                    console.log("expected", expectedRevenue);
                    console.log("ordercount", orderCount, "paymentslength", payments.length);
                    if(orderCount == payments.length){
                        var dashboard = {
                            outStandingOrders: outStandingOrders,
                            nextPaymentDate: nextPaymentDate,
                            payment: nextPayment,
                            revenue: revenue,
                            expectedRevenue: expectedRevenue
                        }
                        console.log("DAS", dashboard);

                        status = 200;
                        response = {message: 'OK', dashboard};
                        return res.status(status).json(response);
                   }
                })
            })
        })
    }else{
        return res.status(500).json({message: 'No details provided'});
    }
}


function parsePayment(payment, callback){

    var revenue = 0, expectedRevenue =0;

    if(payment.amount > 0){
        if(payment.completed && payment.exported){
            console.log("completed payment");
           return callback(null, payment.amount);
        }else{
            Order.findOne({_id: payment.orderId}).exec(function(err, order){
                if (err){
                    return callback(err);
                }
                if(orderService.getOrderStatus(order) == "Send"){
                    console.log("sended order");
                    return callback(null, null, payment.amount);
                }else{
                    return callback();
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I do that, he never calls the function() in the async callback. So he is not even try to send a result

Comment: is there any errors in parsePayment try to put some console.logs and check how many times callback has been called

Comment: It looks like the callback has been called 23 times, the length of payments. I have comment out the if(ordercount == payments.length) but he isn't firing the whole function...

Comment: Haa, found it!, the parsePayment() function has one }else{ which I didn't created. Also completely removed the ordercount. Thanks for your help!